# How do I revert to classic Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar

November, 2017: Google Calendar offered me a new look.  I tried it and would like to revert to the previous version.  I checked the help pages and read that I should click on the little gear icon and then would see "Back to classic Calendar."  But I don't have a little gear icon, and when I go to Calendar Settings, I don't see a way to return to classic calendar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a result of your viewport size.  The "gear/settings" icon only appears intermittently at top right for select viewports.

[image: Google Calendar 2017 settings icon]

It appears between 530 - 600px and above 800px.
You could try zooming in or out to force it to appear and be toggle-ready.

Comment: It's no longer possible.